_next isn't redirecting to custom page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact US</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Contact.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="header">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BinartPhotography/BinartPhotography.github.io/main/background.png" class="logo">
      <div class="banner">
        <div class="navbar">
          <a href="../../index.html">Home</a>
          <a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a>
          <a href="About.html">About</a>
          <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/@email.com" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://binartphotography.github.io/pages/Thanks.html">
      <h1>Contact Us</h1>
      <input type="text" name="first" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" required>
      <input type="text" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" autocomplete="off" required>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" autocomplete="off" required>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="60" name="message" placeholder="Enter text" autocomplete="off" required></textarea>
      <button type="submit"><span></span>Submit message</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>

I have removed the email for privacy reasons but why doesn't _next value redirect to Thanks.html. I linked a whole link lol. I'm using formsubmit.co
I got a success but no redirect to thank you

Bumping the post

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
